# Tag Position in Org Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I create a tag next to a heading it aligns and moves to the right but not as far as I'd like.

How can I make sure the tags are aligned further away from the heading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Emacs 23.3.1 (Org-mode version 6.33x), tags for a heading are right-aligned in accordance with the `org-tags-column` variable.

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-tags-column` <kbd>RET</kbd> to change this to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an oldie, but I just figured out this snippet that works like a charm in my i3wm setup so I might as well share it with everyone.

```
(add-hook 'focus-in-hook 
  (lambda () (progn 
    (setq org-tags-column (- 5 (window-body-width)))) (org-align-all-tags)))

(add-hook 'focus-out-hook 
  (lambda () (progn 
    (setq org-tags-column (- 5 (window-body-width)))) (org-align-all-tags)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `(progn ...)` is doing in this context, having only a single expression inside of it?

Comment: @ChenLevy it does nothing, and can be safely removed. Lambda can contain multiple forms anyway, so never needs a progn.

Comment: please note that focus-in/out-hook was made obsolete in 27.1.